# SAXException=XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: java, soap, xml-parsing

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this parse error?  The XML looks fine to me.  It's failing with `SAXException=XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.`
At this line:

```
Document doc = builder.parse(inputSource);  //fails here
```

Here is the code:

```
        String soapIn = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>\n" +
"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:vid=\"http://videocontrollerchannelmap.queryservice.vcwh.oss.my.company.com/\">\n" +
"   <soapenv:Header/>\n" +
"   <soapenv:Body>\n" +
"      <vid:getInneoquestChannelMap>\n" +
"         <appkey>ONE_CONTROLLER</appkey>\n" +
"         <forceUpdate>true</forceUpdate>\n" +
"      </vid:getInneoquestChannelMap>\n" +
"   </soapenv:Body>\n" +
"</soapenv:Envelope";
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        SOAPMessage newMsg = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(soapIn));
            Document doc = builder.parse(inputSource);  //fails here
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `>` on `"</soapenv:Envelope"`.

Comment: Oh geez.  Staring at it for too long.  Thanks!